# Set color text in textArea

Tags: java, javafx

can't set text color in textArea.

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

String text = textArea.getText();
      
Text colorText = new Text(text);

colorText.setFill(Color.RED);
```

There is no error, but the color of the text still does not change?

Comment: `colorText` is a new node that has nothing to do with your TextArea, except that it’s using the same sequence of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:red");
```

Comment: Yes, it works that way, but why doesn't it work with a setFill?

Comment: Variable text has only value of textArea.
Variable colorText is another field and you set color of field 'colorText'. I don't know if it is even added to window because I don't see whole code.
So summarizing: you set color of 'colorText', not 'textArea'

Comment: What you did is:
1) Create multiline field 'textArea'.
2) Get text which is inside 'textArea' (empty text)
3) Create another field 'colorText' which has the same text as in 'textArea' (empty text)
4) Set color of another field 'colorText'.